# javascript: null variable in function changes its value?

Tags: javascript

Can a null variable in a function become not null? When f enters in function chainF it somehow changes its value? It isn't null anymore.

```
function TestF(){}

TestF.prototype = {
    i: 0,
    f: null,
    chainF: function(g){
        if(this.f == null)
            console.log('f is null');
        var newF = function(){
            if(this.f == null)
                console.log('f is null');
                g();
        };
    this.f = newF;
    return this;
    }
}

t = new TestF();
t.chainF(function(){console.log('g')}).f();
```

Output: 
    f is null (only once)
    g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When chainF is called, it goes in the first if and outputs

> f is null

, then assigns `t.f` to the `newF` function.

Afterwards `t.f` is called (which is now `newF`) on the same object, so `t.f` is not null. 
The next thing to do is call `g()`, outputting

> g

Maybe the misunderstanding is that when you declare the newF function you also think the code is executed. It is not, the function is assigned to `newF` and will be run when it is called (`newF()` or `t.f()`). The call is done on this line:

```
t
  .chainF(function(){console.log('g')})
  .f();                                   // here
```